# Connecting Redis Replica to Master doesn't work

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis

I'm using two EC2 Instance with same security group. I opened 6379 port for the security group.

I added IPs on bind line in /etc/redis/redis.conf.

In first EC2 redis.conf

```
bind 127.0.0.1 (my private IP) (my public IP)
```

feat ) why I can't just mention only my ec2 IP. when 127.0.0.1 doesn't mentioned, i can't restart redis server.

Back to the point, When i set up Second EC2 as replica, it doesn't connect

```
Connecting to MASTER 172.31.43.174:6379
3222:S 11 Nov 2023 15:02:33.332 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
3222:S 11 Nov 2023 15:02:33.332 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
```

But I can connect when i changed the bind line

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

I don't understand why Second EC2 can't reach to First EC2 even though I binded the Second EC2 IP address on First EC2 conf

Comment: did you try to open also the cluster bus port which would be 16379 (assuming you didn't change it)? https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/